# assigning event handlers for potentially long list of socket topics

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am listening to socket messages from Socket.io server in my C# cmd client application.

Once a message is received; I trigger a C# event for all event listeners in the C# application. The C# event listeners are specific to the socket topic.

My question is; is there a better way to assign the event handlers?...for 100s of possible topics?

```
    public static class EventHub(){

        string[] all_topics = { "topic1", "topic2", "topic3" };
        public event EventHandler<TopicEventArgs> On_topic1_event ;
        public event EventHandler<TopicEventArgs> On_topic2_event ;
        public event EventHandler<TopicEventArgs> On_topic3_event ;
  
        public static Go()
        {
            var socket = new SocketIO("http://localhost:11000/");

            foreach (string topic in all_topics) {
                //hookup socket with the topics to listen
                socket.On(topic, response =>               
                {
                    var value = response.GetValue<int>(1);

                    //**HERE** Is there a better way of doing the following?  
                    if (topic == "topic1" && On_topic1_event != null)
                    {
                        On_topic1_event (this, new TopicEventArgs(topic, value));
                    }
                    else if (topic == "topic2" && On_topic2_event != null)
                    {
                        On_topic2_event (this, new TopicEventArgs(topic, value));
                    }
                    else if (topic == "topic3" && On_topic3_event != null)
                    {
                        On_topic3_event (this, new TopicEventArgs (topic, value));
                    }
                    ...
                });
            }


        }
   }

    public class TopicEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public TopicEventArgs(string t, double v)
        {
            this.Value = v;
            this.Topic = t;

        }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
    }




    //usage
    //function Go is called once in apps life cycle.
    ...
    EventHub.Go()
    ...
```

Comment: It's better to implement "Groups logic" like in SignalR. 
Example:
1. User connect to your socket
2. Users send control message "I want to listen topic1"
3. System add user to list of users (Group) that stored (for example) in Dictionary<string,List<UserInfo>> where string is TopicName
4. System send specific topic to specific list of users

Comment: subscribing to the event is same as saying "I want to listen to topic X"...makes the next steps of grouping redundant.  what problem are you trying to solve by grouping?

Answer (score 0):

i am going with this approach. `handler.Invoke` should call the proper event handler with the naming format i am following.

```
foreach (string topic in all_topics) {
    //hookup socket with the topics to listen
    socket.On(topic, response =>               
    {
        var value = response.GetValue<int>(1);

        //event handler methods signature  'On_[topic name]_event'
        MethodInfo handler = thisType.GetMethod("On_"+topic.ToUpper() +"_event", BindingFlags.Public);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            TopicEventArgs[] arg = { new TopicEventArgs(topic, value) };
            handler.Invoke(this, arg);
        }
    });
}
```